# Include a View in Spring MVC

Tags: java, spring-mvc

In my JSP-Template I want to include another JSP-Template, but I don't want to include it by it's path but by it's view name

Not:

```
<jsp:include page="/WEB-INF/jsp/include/header.jsp"/>
```

But:

```
<xxx:yyyyyyyyy page="include/header" />
```

Is that possble?

Answer (score 1):

You can use TagFiles for that. Tag Files contain only fragments of a JSP page and can be parametrized. They have the file ending *.tag and are most commonly stored at WEB-INF/Tags.

See also:
http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/1.4/tutorial/doc/JSPTags5.html

So in your case create a file /WEB-INF/tags/header.tag and add the following to your JSP:

```
<%@ taglib tagdir="/WEB-INF/tags" prefix="h" %>
...
<h:header/>
```

Answer (score 0):

From your problem statement, I understand that you are trying to render a view which is a combination of multiple views, Apache Tiles is package that lets you do exactly that pretty easily. It integrates well with spring as well. [Here](http://www.vaannila.com/spring/spring-tiles-integration-1.html) is a simple tutorial.